# Where can I find packages installed through pip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I installed PRAW (https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with the help of pip. Now I want to change the praw.ini to configure proxy settings but I am unable to find it. Here (https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/configuration_files.html) it says praw.ini must be here (/home/foobar/.config/praw.ini) but the file is not present there. OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and Python version is 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import praw
print praw.__path__
```

For me this gave `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw` and there I found the `praw.ini`:

```
$ l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/praw.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 staff 2380 May 27 12:55 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/praw.ini
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another query. Why isn't grep command able to locate praw.ini.

Comment: `grep` is for finding strings within files, not the files themselves.  You can at most use it to find the files containing a certain string.  But if you want to find a file with a certain name, `grep` would be just a crutch as in `find / | grep praw.ini`.

Answer (score -1):

As per the comments run:

```
updatebd
```

Then:

```
locate praw|grep praw.ini
```

Comment: I am getting nothing. Also when I use "pip freeze" praw is being listed as one of the modules.

Comment: Yes me too I just tested. I'm not sure it the file exists. Let me keep looking.

Comment: `locate` will produce results only after `updatedb` has been run (typically once a day by a cron job).  And `updatedb` will take at least minutes to finish.  And it will just scan the directories it is configured to scan (so no probably user-local ones in virtual envs etc.)